Найти подстроку в свойстве
Есть ли какой-то аналог регулярных выражений? Чтобы извлечь часть строки из свойства если оно соответствует шаблону.

В модуле Utils есть функция regexPatternMatch
по аналогии можно сделать свои функции использующиеся в postgres SQL
https://docs.lsfusion.org/FORMULA_operator/
